# Clarify the steps: what happened in this mathematical modelling of TSP?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Source: http://examples.gurobi.com/traveling-salesman-problem

I don't get this part: (look at the source)

[image]

I get that $x_{ij}$ is equal to 3, but why the "> 2" ?

And what is the deal with subtracting one from a set? How do you even do that?

How come $|\{1,2,3\}|-1 = 3 > 2$   ?!?

Isn't
$$|\{1,2,3\}|-1=3>2$$
The same as writing:
$$2=3>2$$
?

I don't get this part at all, please elaborate on what happened in as simple language as possible. My level is high school final year.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a slightly confusing way of writing it especially if you are used to reading everything left to right.

Expanded, what the author is saying is that the “no subtour” constraint is

$$\sum_S x_{i,j} \leq \left| S \right| -1$$

The number of edges involved in any proper subset S is at most the number of points (cities) minus one.

Take the left hand side of this constraint for the set $\{1,2,3\}$

$$\sum_{i,j \in \{1,2,3\}, i\neq j}x_{i,j} = 3$$

And the RHS is

$$\left|\{1,2,3\}\right|-1 =2$$

Where $\left|\{1,2,3\}\right|$ is the number of elements in the set, ie 3.

The constraint is violated since $3\gt 2$.

Comment: What is $E$ equal to, would it be correct to say, that it is equal to: $$E=\{v_{12}, v_{23}, v_{31}\}$$ and so on?

Comment: Yes that’s correct. And x_{ij} =1 if the edge is in the tour and =0 if not in the tour

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, please would you mind “accepting” it. If not, please leave another comment and i will explain further